# Indeterminate-length big-endian to little-endian conversion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, bitwise, serialization

I have a need to convert wire encoding (big-endian) to little-endian in Python.

The conversion needs to happen as a separate function; I am not allowed to change the function that reads the byte stream because it will break a lot of other functions.

The best I can think of is this:

```
def be_to_le(value: int) -> int:
    assert isinstance(value, int)
    numbytes = len(f"0{value:x}") >> 1
    if numbytes == 1:
        return value
    rslt = 0
    for b in value.to_bytes(numbytes, byteorder="little"):
        rslt <<= 8
        rslt |= b
    return rslt
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate number of bytes, better use:

```
numbytes = math.ceil(value.bit_length() / 8)
```

And then you can just:

```
def be_to_le(value: int) -> int:
    numbytes = math.ceil(value.bit_length() / 8)
    return int.from_bytes(value.to_bytes(numbytes, byteorder="little"), byteorder="big")
```

Comment: Ooohhh... so `int` has a `bit_length()` method? That's news to me... Thanks for telling me that! I'll probably not use `math.ceil` though. `(n + 7) >> 3` might be better since it keeps everything in `int` land. Anyways, thanks!